# When typing something in the URL bar in Safari with google as my default search engine without pressing "enter", does google log what I've typed?

Tags: logging

When typing in the URL bar in safari with google as my default search engine without pressing enter (i.e not actually searching), does the text I've typed or my IP get logged to google?

Answer (score 1):

If you have search suggestions enabled, which sends each keystroke to Google so that it can provide you with a list of possible completions, then yes, they will know your IP. Otherwise you will only connect to them when you press enter. I do not know if Safari uses suggestions by default.

Comment: Hi, is autocomplete the same as suggestions? For example, when I type something in the URL, there's a drop down menu with possible completions I can choose, it doesn't complete in the URL itself.

Comment: Yes, search suggestions is what I meant. My bad.